# TypeORM How to use substring in orderBy

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I'm trying to sort a table by substring of the string column (originalUrl).

I executed a raw SQL query and it worked well:

```sql
SELECT * FROM photo ORDER BY SUBSTRING(originalUrl, -40, 8) ASC;
```

But this code prints an error:

```js
const [photos, count] = await this.photoRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('photo')
        .orderBy('SUBSTRING(photo.originalUrl, -40, 8)', 'ASC')
        .getManyAndCount();
```

And the error is:

```
Error: "SUBSTRING(photo" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?
```

I googled this issue many times but I was not able to find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

#### EDIT:

I checked the console and found out that the alias of `originalUrl` column in `photo` table was `photo_originalUrl` so I tried this code and worked well!

```js
const [photos, count] = await this.photoRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('photo')
        .orderBy(`SUBSTRING("photo_originalUrl", -40, 8)`, 'ASC')
        .getManyAndCount();
```

#### EDIT2:

Actually, it didn't work. It returns a substring of `"photo_originalUrl"` string, not its column value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sample query -

```
return await getRepository(Entity)
.createQueryBuilder("entity")
.orderBy('SUBSTRING(entity.sample_attribute, -40, 8)', 'ASC')
.printSql()
.getManyAndCount();
```

It got executed successfully. I think your problem is not how to use `SUBSTRING` in `ORDER BY`. There might be an issue while getting the `photo` repository.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `.orderBy('photo.originalUrl', 'ASC')` and it worked... Only `.orderBy('SUBSTRING(photo.originalUrl, -40, 8)', 'ASC')` didn't work. Finally, I solved this issue by using another alias!